# htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

im trying to redirect a subdirectory and everything beneath it to another url.  for example,

http://example.com/example/ should go to http://cname.example.com/example/.  Im not sure how to do this in apache. I know how to rewrite from a subdirectory to the root but nothing else.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect 301 /example/ http://cname.example.com/example/

[EDIT: Add Link]
http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml